# TXTextControl Error in text filter: Unknown format

Tags: c#, .net, txtextcontrol

In an asp.net application the method `TXTextControl.ServerTextControl.Load(path, type)` throws the following exception: Error in text filter: Unknown format. (01-1D01)

Even though the file is a .htm file and the type is HTMLFormat, the component fails to load the file throwing that exception as a result.
I'm using version 12.0 of the component, not sure where to look next

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is really old now but i just ran into this exact problem,
and this was the top result when i searched for it.
So if anyone else comes across this problem here is the cause of the problem that i discovered.

I was loading content that was supposed to be RTF but the actual content was plain-text. I updated the input content to be proper RTF format and the error message went away.
I suggest verifying that the loaded co

Answer (score 0):

Although I´m not used to work with the SERVER component of TxControl, I think you may utilize the LOAD directly from the component, not the DLL itself.

In WinForms we add the reference into project and add the component to the page/form. And we load the file using the following structure:

```
  1) Load into a mem variable.
  2) Load into Editor from that mem variable.
```

See:

```
  Dim TextoOriginal As String = File.ReadAllText(DataFile)
  TextControl1.Load(TextoOriginal, TXTextControl.StringStreamType.RichTextFormat)
```